# Игра в числа НАОБОРОТ

Tags: python

Пользователь загадывает, компьютер отгадывает, нельзя использовать random, нужно использовать циклы. Ввод: Загадайте число: 5, Ответ: Вы загадали число 5 (print нельзя, так слишком легко), PYTHON

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Компьютер отгадает число за доли секунды, если использовать циклы, какой смысл?

Comment: не отгадает...нужно же промежуточные данные от пользователя получать... а он "медленный" ))

Comment: Это не игра "отгадай число", а последовательный перебор всех возможных значений (брутфорс)

Comment: Ну если бутфорс, тогда никогда не отгадает. Ибо интерфейсы не синхронизированы. ))

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотели так?:

```py
# Тут можете использовать try/except ValueError
a = int(input("Введите число: "))
i = 0
while True:
    if i == a:
        print("Ваше число:", str(i))
        break
    elif i * -1 == a:
        print("Ваше число:", str(i * -1))
        break
    i += 1
```

Версия с `tkinter`:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label
# Тут можете использовать try/except ValueError
a = int(input("Введите число: "))
i = 0
while True:
    if i == a:
        break
    elif i * -1 == a:
        i *= -1
        break
    i += 1

root = Tk()
l = Label(text = "Ваше число: " + str(i))
l.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Версия с `tkinter` (v2):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Entry, Button, StringVar

def nazvanie(a):
    i = 0
    while True:
        if i == a:
            break
        elif i * -1 == a:
            i *= -1
            break
        i += 1
    return [str(a), str(i)]

root = Tk()
root.geometry("270x50")

l2 = ""
tv = StringVar(root)

def result(num):
    global l2
    try:
        l2.unpack()
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    try:
        num = int(num)
    except ValueError:
        return
    b = nazvanie(num)
    l2 = Label(root, text = "Число: " + b[1])
    l2.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

l = Label(root, text = "Введите число:")
l.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
a = Entry(root, textvariable = tv)
a.grid(column = 1, row = 0)
btn = Button(root, text = "Угадать", command = lambda r = tv: result(r.get()))
btn.grid(column = 2, row = 0)
root.mainloop()
```

Версия с `Exception`:

```py
# Тут можете использовать try/except ValueError
a = int(input("Введите число: "))
i = 0
while True:
    if i == a:
        raise Exception("Ваше число: " + str(i))
        break
    elif i * -1 == a:
        raise Exception("Ваше число: " + str(i * -1))
        break
    i += 1
```

Comment: print низя... ))

Comment: А как вывести число? В вопросе имелось ввиду, что нельзя просто написать `print(input())` (наверное)

Comment: как... например графическими интерфейсами... или наоборот... байт кодом....

Comment: Добавлена версия без `print` с использованием `tkinter`

Comment: нет предела совершенству... не умеет пользователь числа вводить. Предоставьте ему кнопки на экране, что бы он мог их "потычить"... )

Comment: @A_Vaclav Надо генерить случайное число и просто спрашивать у пользователя (при помощи кнопок, естественно) "Вы хотите загадать это число? [Да/Нет]". А то ещё вводить чего-то, да ещё и число придумывать... Сложно... :)

Comment: А вместо print можно использовать write, pprint, exception с текстом выкинуть. Да мало ли чего умеет в терминал писать. :)

Comment: низя случайное генерить по условию...

Comment: И не нужно ничего генерить. Вы "чугунивыевый" шкаф на ярмарке с телевизором. На экране мерцает большой красявый вопрос - "ИГРАЕМ?" и пониже кнопочка - "играть". Тыкнули в кнопку - выдаем новый экран. На нем счет попыток, предлагаемый вариант числа, три кнопки: больше равно меньше.  Кнопка равно все решает. При нажатии на нее на экране демонстрируется жизнерадостная анимация с воспроизведением веселой задорной мелодии... как то так ))

Comment: Добавлена версия с `tkinter` (v2), хоть там и нет анимаций, дополнительных кнопок (только одна), музыки и т. д.